# Each line in plot with different color

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 25}, {1, 150}, {2, 150}, {3, 0}, {4, 150}, {5, 
   150}, {6, 0}, {7, 200}},
 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Orange}, {Blue, 
    Dashed}, {Orange}, {Green}, {Green}, {Black}, {Red}},
 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, 250}}
 
 ]
```

How can I make each plot line in the plot (7 in total) to have a different color or dashes?. I am trying to accomplished that using  `PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Orange}, {Yellow,  Dashed}, {Orange}, {Green}, {Brown}, {Black}, {Red}}` but it does not work.

Comment: You'll have to construct it by hand. ListLinePlot does not consider the segments as separate lines, as you can see for yourself by running: `Cases[yourListLinePlot, _Line, All] `. There is only one Line object in the results.

Comment: @ MarcoB thanks! I see. But how can i individually construct it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 25}, {1, 150}, {2, 150}, {3, 0}, {4, 150}, {5, 150}, {6, 0}, {7, 200}};

styles = {{Blue}, {Orange}, {Blue, Dashed}, {Orange}, {Green}, {Green}, {Black}, {Red}};

ListLinePlot[Partition[data, 2, 1],
 PlotStyle -> styles, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, 250}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html):

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 Mesh -> {data[[All, 1]]}, 
 MeshShading -> Prepend[None][Directive /@ styles], 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, 250}}]
```

[image]

Finally, you can use `Graphics` as follows:

```
Graphics[Thread[{Most[Directive /@ styles], 
   Line /@ Partition[data, 2, 1]}], 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, 250}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1 / GoldenRatio, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[data, 
  Thread[{Most[Directive /@ styles], Line /@ Partition[Range@Length@data, 2, 1]}]], 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, 250}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 Axes -> True]
```

> ```
>  same picture
> ```